# Import from sql file without command line

Tags: php, mysql

Using PHP, I have a sql file which I want to import into my database.
Unfortunately, I can't use any command (`php exec`).

How can I do that (without phpMyAdmin and co) ?

Thanks.

Comment: phpMyAdmin/adminer, if you want to do it via a UI ...

Comment: I don't have phpMyAdmin. using only php... :-(

Comment: So what? Adminer is _one single script file_ that you upload to your server, and that’s it ... https://www.adminer.org/

Comment: I have to do that programmatically, without any UI (this import tool should be used by anyone)

Comment: Well then just say that directly next time ...

Comment: you're right, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or with PHP only. 
Please note the SQL file should include `USE database` statement(s) because mysqli_connect doesn't use a default database.

**SQL file code**

```
USE stackoverflow; 

CREATE TABLE test() (

 id int 
);
```

**PHP code**

```
<?php 
 $fileContentsString = file_get_contents([path_to_sql_file]); 

 $connection = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "username", "password");

 mysqli_multi_query($connection, $fileContentsString);
?>
```

Comment: I will try that !

Answer (score 0):

Better use MySQL Workbench. MySQL Workbench is a visual database design tool that integrates SQL development, administration, database design, creation and maintenance into a single integrated development environment for the MySQL database system

Comment: Thanks, but I can't install it. using only php... :-(

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to **phpMyAdmin**, then you should be able to create a database 
[create database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5ewd.png)
using the **xampp** or **wampp** GUI, select the newly created database and then click **import**  [import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7151.png) and then select the sql file [select sql file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrrsJ.png) you want to upload and click **go** [click go to complete process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOCcV.png) at the bottom, it should then bring a message Import successful.... after the entire process, you are good to go

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have phpMyAdmin. using only php... :-(